# Simple Matrix matlab mannipulation

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

This question relates to basic linear algebra:

```
w = [100 200 300 400]' 
M = [0.3378 0.1800;0.1252 0.1200; 0.3759 0.4900; 0.1611 0.2100]
```

The equation relating them is w = Mx. We are told to find x. While x is just simply w*M^-1, the matrix dimensions do not match for the multiplication. Is there a way for me to obtain x?

The hint given to us is to "check rref([M w]) to see if the equation relating x and w is consistent."

Comment: Homework questions without *any* kind of own effort is [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By multiplying vector x by the M matrix, you obtain:

```
0.3378x + 0.1800y = 100
0.1252x + 0.1200y = 200
0.3759x + 0.4900y = 300
0.1611x + 0.2100y = 400
```

Which is a system of equations.
You can put this into an Augmented Matrix and solve for vector x by solving for **rref**(M)

By being able to get to **rref** form, you show you are able to take the inverse of the Matrix and therefore are able to solve for vector x.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following equation to calculate x,

```
x=pinv(M' * M) * M' * w
```

This is because, M'*M is a square matrix. You will get x as a 2 by 1 matrix. Since we are taking the pseudo inverse we don't have to worry about the singularity of M'*M

Comment: Here, pinv(M' * M) * M' is equal to pinv(M).

Answer (score 0):

Every least squares problem should use the backslash operator (or `linsolve`) and no echelon forms or Gauss elimination.

The solution is given by `M\w` which does essentially what Imesha Sudasingha wrote but it is numerically much more stable and optimized with backslash operator.